# AutoMapper Member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, types, automapper, instance

I get this error

> Member 'Mapper.Map(object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

with the following code (.NET Framework 4.6 and AutoMapper 7.0.1).

Note that I follow the same code from another project on .NET 8 and the latest version of AutoMapper which doesn't result in this error.

I've already read that this error can appear with static members, but it doesn't seem to be the issue here. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve it?

```
public class DatumModel
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedDatumModel : DatumModel
{
    public int OtherValue { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<DatumModel, ExtendedDatumModel>();
        });

        var mapper = new Mapper(config);

        var data = new List<DatumModel>();

        data.Add(new DatumModel
        {
            Value = 1
        });

        foreach (var datum in data)
        {
            // error happens here
            var extendedDatum = mapper.Map<ExtendedDatumModel>(datum); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no version 4.6 of Automapper, and even if there was, it would be from 2016 which is long before .NET 8 was available.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edited the version to 7.0.1 with .NET Framework 4.6. It is the 12.0.1 which I use with my other project on .NET 8. I've just realised that managing the package versions seem to be a real ordeal!!

Comment: You can still use version 10 with .NET Framework 4.6x which means this code will still work.

Comment: Are you sure? If I go to https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/10.0.0#supportedframeworks-body-tab, it is listed .NET Framework net461, net462, net47, etc. but not net46... and unfortunately I don't think I can upgrade (I work for a large company where everything is locked...)

Answer (score 0):

This code works with latest AutoMapper nuget package, it is because of the differences that you have (you are using very, very old version of a package).

So primary solution would be - upgrade the package to latest version 12.0.1.

Secondary solution is to adjust the code:

Define file `AutoMapperConfiguration.cs` with mapper configuration:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure(IMapperConfigurationExpression config)
    {
        config.CreateMap<DatumModel, ExtendedDatumModel>();
    }
}
```

In your application startup code add this line:

```
Mapper.Initialize(AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure);
```

And then use static class `Mapper` and its static `Map` method.

Comment: OP is only getting the error because they are using a very old version of Automapper. They really just need to update to v9 or higher and their code will work fine.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, thanks, i assumed that obvious, but added necessary note.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michal for your explanation. It works well!

Unfortunately, I don't think that I can use a latter version. I only have access to Visual Studio Pro 2015 and .NET Framework 4.6 at most (whereas I use the Community 2022 version on my own computer). Based on what I can see on the NuGet website https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/7.0.1#supportedframeworks-body-tab, the latest compatible version of AutoMapper is 7.0.1. But that something I should investigate more ; It seems that there have been major changes from .NET Framework 4.6 to 4.6.1.

Comment: The version of Automapper being used has nothing to do with the version of Visual Studio.